# No host specified in URI file:///null

Tags: flutter, api, imagepicker

i am trying to display the image that I am getting as a response from API.
below is the code for displaying the image -:

```
String ProfilePic;

                                 CircleAvatar(
                                    radius: 80,
                                    backgroundImage:
                                    ProfilePic != null ?
                                      NetworkImage('$ProfilePic'):
                                        // AssetImage('$ProfilePic') :
                                        AssetImage('assets/favicon.png'),
                                  ),
```

As a response, I am getting this data from API -: I/flutter ( 4230): pexels-lisa-1107717.jpg

and when I use it I get following error -:

```
======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///null

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2662:9)
#1      _HttpClient.getUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2573:48)
#2      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:89:59)
#3      NetworkImage.load (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:50:14)
#4      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:505:13)
#5      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:380:22)
#6      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:503:83)
#7      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:333:9)
#8      ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:464:26)
#9      SynchronousFuture.then (package:flutter/src/foundation/synchronous_future.dart:41:35)
#10     ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:461:11)
#14     ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:453:16)
#15     ImageProvider.resolve (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:330:5)
#16     DecorationImagePainter.paint (package:flutter/src/painting/decoration_image.dart:258:55)
#17     _BoxDecorationPainter._paintBackgroundImage (package:flutter/src/painting/box_decoration.dart:465:20)
#18     _BoxDecorationPainter.paint (package:flutter/src/painting/box_decoration.dart:483:5)
#19     RenderDecoratedBox.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2162:17)
#20     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2409:7)
#21     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:189:13)
#22     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
#23     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2409:7)
#24     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:189:13)
#25     RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2794:15)
#26     RenderStack.paintStack (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:629:5)
#27     RenderStack.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:645:7)
#28     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2409:7)
#29     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:189:13)
#30     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
#31     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2409:7)
#32     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:189:13)
#33     RenderShiftedBox.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:79:15)
#34     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2409:7)
#35     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:189:13)
#36     RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2794:15)
#37     RenderFlex.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:1078:7)
#38     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2409:7)
#39     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:189:13)
#40     RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2794:15)
#41     RenderFlex.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:1078:7)
#42     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2409:7)
#43     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:189:13)
#44     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:140:15)
#45     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2409:7)
#46     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:189:13)
#47     RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2794:15)
#48     RenderFlex.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:1078:7)
#49     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2409:7)
#50     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:189:13)
#51     _RenderSingleChildViewport.paint.paintContents (package:flutter/src/widgets/single_child_scroll_view.dart:619:17)
#52     PaintingContext.pushLayer (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:398:12)
#53     PaintingContext.pushClipRect (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:454:7)
#54     _RenderSingleChildViewport.paint (package:flutter/src/widgets/single_child_scroll_view.dart:623:40)
#55     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2409:7)
#56     PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:141:11)
#57     PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:100:5)
#58     PipelineOwner.flushPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:979:29)
#59     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:455:19)
#60     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:883:13)
#61     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:319:5)
#62     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1143:15)
#63     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1080:9)
#64     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:996:5)
#68     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:166:10)
#69     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:270:5)
#70     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:129:31)
(elided 6 frames from dart:async)
Image provider: NetworkImage("null", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("null", scale: 1.0)
====================================================================================================
```

i have used network image but still, I am not able to display the image. i have tried other solutions too but nothing seems to work.

can anyone help me with displaying this?

Comment: it will be the case that the profilepic can be  null , can you please add the sample json mock where you are fetching the data.

Answer (score 0):

Your check is wrong it should be this way
`ProfilePic != null ? NetworkImage('$ProfilePic'):AssetImage('assets/favicon.png'),`

Comment: still, i am getting error -: Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///pexels-lisa-1107717.jpg

Comment: At least now you are actually getting the url.  Are you sure it's a network image? The response is just the asset name + extension. Is this file locally ? Then you can use `AssetImage('assets/$ProfilePic')`

Comment: i tried that but i get error - Unable to load asset: assets/pexels-lisa-1107717.jpg

Comment: Where does this asset live?

Comment: i am getting this in api response.

Comment: Well it's wrong. You can't load an image with just its name.

Comment: so the data in the api is wrong or my calling?

Comment: Exactly, you will need the `host` where those images are hosted.